# Qt - Selecting multiple folders/directories using a dialog

Tags: qt, folderbrowserdialog

I want to achieve something like the following:

[image]

Where I can select multiple folders across multiple drives and retrieve the folder paths of those selected.  Qt only has a crude multi-folder selection feature, but it does not support selected folders from other drives etc.

Can anyone guide me on how to create such a dialog?  Better yet, does any one have any sample code I could use (this is an extension to an old project, and I'd much rather save my time and not re-invent the wheel!)

Thanks

Comment: i think you have to write code on your own.

Comment: True, but I'd like to know how to approach it.  Sub-class what, implement what? etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [QFileSystemModel](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qfilesystemmodel.html) for represent filesystem on [QTreeView](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtreeview.html). [This example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/itemviews-dirview.html) explains how to do that.

For checkbox issue, according to [this list archives](http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2005-08/msg00516.html):

> The simplest way to do this (I can think of, at least) is to subclass 
>   QDirModel and override `flags`, `data` and `setData`:
>
> `flags` should add `Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable` to the returned flags
>   `data` should return the `Qt::CheckState` of the queried index if the role  parameter is `Qt::CheckStateRole`
>   `setData` should store the check state of the index
>
> Or, even better, this should work with a QProxyModel pretty much the 
>   same way (after all, "favor object composition over class
>   inheritance").

Note that [QDirModel class](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtreeview.html) is obsolete. You may not use that on newer Qt versions. I recommend to use [QFileSystemModel](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qfilesystemmodel.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
####### Retrieve a list of directories with wxPython-Phoenix   - tested on python3.5
### installation instruction for wxPython-Phoenix  : https://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20install%20wxPython#Installing_wxPython-Phoenix_using_pip
### modified from : https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.agw.multidirdialog.html
import os
import wx
import wx.lib.agw.multidirdialog as MDD

# Our normal wxApp-derived class, as usual
app = wx.App(0)
dlg = MDD.MultiDirDialog(None, title="Custom MultiDirDialog", defaultPath=os.getcwd(),  # defaultPath="C:/Users/users/Desktop/",
                         agwStyle=MDD.DD_MULTIPLE|MDD.DD_DIR_MUST_EXIST)

if dlg.ShowModal() != wx.ID_OK:
    print("You Cancelled The Dialog!")
    dlg.Destroy()


paths = dlg.GetPaths()

#Print directories' path and files 
for path in enumerate(paths):
    print(path[1])
    directory= path[1].replace('OS (C:)','C:')
    print(directory)
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        print(file)

dlg.Destroy()
app.MainLoop()
```